# Text-to-speech like Option-Esc in macOS

Tags: accessibility, text-to-speech, orca

I'm considering switching over to Ubuntu from macOS at the moment, and the one feature I can't seem to find a replacement for is macOS's Speech tools, in particular the "Speak selected text when the key is pressed" option in `System Preferences > Accessibility > Speech`. I use this extensively on macOS. Does Ubuntu/GNOME have any kind of tool like this?

I'm aware of Orca, but based on my experience fiddling around with it, Orca constantly blurts out the text under the cursor as opposed to just speaking the text that is selected on command.